# Modifying a "flag" in an IPA

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have this app which takes 2 hours to compile and I usually need to make about 9 of those for each client. Basically, all that changes is the URL for the services. I was wondering if there's a way to modify a variable in the IPA file itself by way of uncompressing or something(?) so that I can save that time that I need to put in to build 9 IPAs.

Comment: 2 hours?? seriously? :O

Comment: You can use the settings for this. In your settings.bundle, add a multivalue entry with the desired options. Then in your code, you should read the selected value with `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"yourKey"]` and execute some code according to the selected option.